# save huge dataset from excel in MySQL, does not save all rows

Tags: mysql, node.js, excel

I have more or less 20000 rows in my excel file (exported from another Database based Tool), which i would like to save in my Database.

```
if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');

var xlsx = "tmp8704.xlsx";
var url = "extFiles/"+xlsx;
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
var dataXLS;

oReq.onload = function(e) {
var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

/* convert data to binary string */
var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
var arr = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
var bstr = arr.join("");

/* Call XLSX */
var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});
var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
/* Get worksheet */
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

dataXLS = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {header:1});

var mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  user: 'muser',
  password: 'massword',
  database: 'matabase'
});

connection.connect((err) => {
if(err) {
  return console.log(err.stack);
}
console.log("Connection succesfully established");
});

for(var x in dataXLS){
  if(parseInt(x)+2 != dataXLS.length) {

      var myNumber = dataXLS[parseInt(x)+2][6];
      console.log("Stelle " + x + " :" + dataXLS[parseInt(x)+2][0] + " " + dataXLS[parseInt(x)+2][1] + " " + parseFloat(myNumber));

      $queryString = "INSERT INTO `articles` (articleno,text,price) VALUES ("+parseInt(dataXLS[parseInt(x)+2][0])+",'"+dataXLS[parseInt(x)+2][1]+"',"+parseFloat(myNumber)+");";


      connection.query($queryString, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(err) {
          return console.log("An error ocurred with the query", err);
        }
      });

  } else {
    console.log(parseInt(x)+2);
    console.log(dataXLS.length); //19610
    break;
  }
}

connection.end(() => {
  console.log("Connection successfully closed");
});
}

oReq.send();
```

First question: It is saving data in my table, but only time after time, and not all of it. Why?

Second question: Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: Try not to insert inside for, but in one big query. INSERT (...) VALUES ($array[0]['col1'],$array[0]['col2']),($array[1]['col1'],$array[1]['col2']) and so on.

Comment: please explain the "big picture" of your solution, to get answers to your second question. Explain why you need excel, when the data come "from another database tool" (which db tool? which database?), why can't you just connect to the source database, and do you need a simple solution for a data migration that's done once, or do you need frequent executions of this job?

Comment: for performance reasons, prepared statements would be more performant, in general. if it's a migration job that's done just once, create a script with several INSERT statements from your excel sheet.

Comment: @RadosławHalicki the excel file has 20000 entities :). What I could do is to generate the query-String inside a for loop. Would that solve all issues?

Comment: @ChristophBimminger what we have is a "stock-software", where i can export data as excel-files. I need the values (article-no and prices) for my webapplication. So far, I replace the values in my MySQL-DB manually, whenever something is changed in the stock-software. My intention is, to build an little apllication (electron) to do it automatically, which means export the excel file, and load it up to our server with one-click. when it is 'working', I will have to implement a little application for windows user with c# and connect to it with an odbc, but that is the next step :)

Answer (score 0):

When I had to export large Excel sheets into MySQL, I used [this website](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm). You will have to export your excel file as a csv and tweak the settings on the site somewhat, but I found that it was fast and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement a VBA macro in excel which creates a set of insert statements for all data in your excel sheet. or, if you don't want to use macros, just define a new excel sheet where you define a simple formula such as

```
=CONCAT("INSERT INTO xxx (a,b,c) values (";Sheet2!A1;", ";Sheet2!A2);")")
```

which creates insert statements on sheet 1 for all data you paste on sheet 2

(depending on datatypes, you have to add ' around the data columns, insert some data type conversion,...)

then copy the formula down for all your 20000 rows, and you get 20000 insert statements. alternatively, you could change it to update statements when you need to update existing records.